# How to make Qt Dbus more responsive? (When the main thread is busy)

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, dbus, qtdbus

I am using Qt DBus to monitor signals. However, as the main Qt thread is often busy with a long running task (a design I currently cannot change), there is a long delay between sending a qt-dbus message by another program an the slot being called. How can I reduce this delay?

I connect a slot to be called when a signal is received something like so:

```
#include <QtDBus>
#include <QString>
#include <QObject>

MyDbus : public QObject {
public:
    MyDbus() {
        QDBusConnection::systemBus().connect("", "path", "interface.com", "member", this, SLOT(mySlot(QString)));
    }

private slots:
    void mySlot(QString& message) const {
        // Do something.
    }
 };
```

Using Qt 4.8.6.

Comment: Couldn't you just run the d-bus calls from a background thread?

Comment: According to this, no.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058519/how-to-use-qt-dbus-bindings-without-blocking-the-main-thread

Comment: In that case it seems like the only two solutions would be a) change your code so it doesn't block the main thread, or b) patch Qt so it doesn't have this d-bus restriction.

Comment: Move whatever blocks from the main thread to a worker thread. Presto.